# How do you add a link title to the post meta tag code?

Tags: wordpress, metadata, title

My code is `if ($link->getAttribute('title') == '' || empty($link->getAttribute('title')))` and I am wondering how to get a link title to appear when the tags are at the bottom of a post.

I recently tried https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19292/automatically-add-title-attribute-to-links-in-wordpress but it broke on the line `if ($link->getAttribute('title') == '' || empty($link->getAttribute('title')))`

This is what shows in my source: `Tags: <a href="http://revivemediaservices.com/tag/destin-web-design/" rel="tag">Web Design</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your code is encoding HTML entities, which in this case you do not want. For this, instead of Web Design you get the code behind it.

You need to provide in which line these links are echoed/printed. I anticipate `html-entitites()` function is used there. `html-entitites` function is necessary here, but it is necessary to encode this bold part only: `<a hreft='http://example.com>`**Example Description**`</a>`, so your code has to be modified IMO.